# Dataflowblock stops updating UI but still runs the action?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

This issue is really hard to debug, not always happens (not happen in a short time so that I can just debug the code easily) and looks like no one out there has had the similar issue like this? (I've googled for hours without finding anything related to this issue).

In a short word, my dataflow network works fine at some point until I find out that the terminal block (which updates the UI) seems to stop working (no new data updated on the UI) whereas all the upwards dataflow blocks are still working fine. So it's like there is some disconnection between the other blocks and the ui block here.

Here is my detailed dataflow network, let's check out first before I'm going to explain more about the issue:

```
//the network graph first
[raw data block] 
-> [switching block] -> [data counting block]
                     -> [processing block] -> [ok result block] -> [completion monitoring]
                                           -> [not ok result block] -> [completion monitoring]

//in the UI code behind where I can consume the network and plug-in some other blocks for updating
//like this:
     [ok result block] -> [ok result counting block]
     [not ok result block] -> [other ui updating]
```

The block `[ok result block]` is a `BroadcastBlock` which pushes result to the `[ok result counting block]`. The issue I've described partly here is this `[ok result counting block]` seems to be disconnected from `[ok result block]`.

```
var options = new DataflowBlockOptions { EnsureOrdered = false };
var execOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 80 };

//[raw data block]
var rawDataBlock = new BufferBlock<Input>(options);

//[switching block]
var switchingBlock = new TransformManyBlock<Input,Input>(e => new[] {e,null});

//[data counting block]
var dataCountingBlock = new BroadcastBlock<Input>(null);

//[processing block]
var processingBlock = new TransformBlock<Input,int>(async e => {
    //call another api to compute the result
    var result = await …;
    //rollback the input for later processing (some kind of retry)
    if(result < 0){
       //per my logging, there is only one call dropping 
       //in this case
       Task.Run(rollback);
    }
    //local function to rollback
    async Task rollback(){
      await rawDataBlock.SendAsync(e).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return result;
}, execOptions);

//[ok result block]
var okResultBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(null, options);

//[not ok result block]
var notOkResultBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(null, options);

//[completion monitoring]
var completionMonitoringBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(e => {
     if(rawDataBlock.Completion.IsCompleted && processingBlock.InputCount == 0){
          processingBlock.Complete();
     }
}, execOptions);

//connect the blocks to build the network
rawDataBlock.LinkTo(switchingBlock);
switchingBlock.LinkTo(processingBlock, e => e != null);
switchingBlock.LinkTo(dataCountingBlock, e => e == null);

processingBlock.LinkTo(okResultBlock, e => e >= 9);
processingBlock.LinkTo(notOkResultBlock, e => e < 9);

okResultBlock.LinkTo(completionMonitoringBlock);
notOkResultBlock.LinkTo(completionMonitoringBlock);
```

In the UI code behind, I plug in some other UI blocks to update the info. Here I'm using `WPF` but I think it does not matter here:

```
var uiBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
     TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
};
dataCountingBlock.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<int>(e => {
      //these are properties in the VM class, which is bound to the UI (xaml view)
      RawInputCount++;
}, uiBlockOptions));

okResultBlock.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<int>(e => {
      //these are properties in the VM class, which is bound to the UI (xaml view)
      ProcessedCount++;
      OkResultCount++;
}, uiBlockOptions));

notOkResultBlock.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<int>(e => {
      //these are properties in the VM class, which is bound to the UI (xaml view)
      ProcessedCount++;
      PendingCount = processingBlock.InputCount;
}, uiBlockOptions));
```

I do have code monitoring the completion status of the blocks: `rawDataBlock`, `processingBlock`, `okResultBlock`, `notOkResultBlock`.
I also have other logging code inside the `processingBlock` to help diagnosing.

So as I said, after some fairly long time (about 1 hour with about 600K items processed, actually this number says nothing about the issue, it could be random), the network seems to still run fine except that some counts (ok result, not ok result) are not updated, as if the `okResultBlock` and `notOkResultBlock` were disconnected from the `processingBlock` OR they were disconnected from the UI blocks (which updates the UI). I ensure that the `processingBlock` is still working (no exception logged and the results are still written to file), the `dataCountingBlock` is still working well (with new count updated on the UI), all the blocks `processingBlock`, `okResultBlock`, `notOkResultBlock` are not completed (their completions are `.ContinueWith` a task which logs out the status and nothing logged).

So it's really stuck there. I don't have any clue about why it could stop working like that. This could only happen when we use a black-box library like `TPL Dataflow`. I know it may also be hard for you to diagnose, imagine and think about possibilities. I just asked here for suggestions to solve this as well as any shared experience (about the similar issues) from you and possibly some guesses about what could cause such kind of issue in `TPL Dataflow`

**UPDATE**:

I've successfully reproduced the bug one more time and before I had prepared some code to write down some info to help debugging. The issue now keeps down to this point: The `processingBlock` somehow does not actually push/post/send any msg to all the linked blocks (including the `okResultBlock` and `notOkResultBlock`) AND even a new block (prepended with `DataflowLinkOptions` having `Append` of false) linked to it could not receive any message (the result). As I said the `processBlock` does seem to still work fine (its `Action` does run the code inside and produce result logging normally). So this is still a very strange issue.

In a short word, the problem now becomes why the `processBlock` could not send/post its messages to all the other linked blocks? Is there any possible cause for that to occur? How to know if the blocks are linked successfully (after the call to `.LinkTo`)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219451/discussion-on-question-by-hopeless-dataflowblock-stops-updating-ui-but-still-run).

Comment: Could you update your question by removing all the unrelated stuff, and just leaving the bare minimum dataflow blocks required in order to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias actually the code is unchanged. I just add more code (handled by a `Button`'s click), that code is run only when I've detected (by my eyes looking at the UI) that the bug has occurred. So the code I run on that button click is just to write the blocks' status at that time (the broadcast blocks `notOkResultBlock` and `okResultBlock` keep the last value they received and not any new posted to them), I even tried linking the `processingBlock` to a new block (as I said in my UPDATE) but that new block does not log out anything.

Comment: Sorry, without a concrete, minimal, reproducible example I won't be able to help any further.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias never mind, I've just found out that the `DataflowBlock.Completion` task somehow always has the status of `WaitingForActivation`, that's really strange, I hope that at least it should switch between different statuses like Running, ...I do believe that my issue here is related to some very hidden bug in the `TPL Dataflow` library, it's not easy to be reproduced, may require you to wait for a long time. If you don't mind, I'll try cloning (with some possible adjustment) my project and send you later. Actually my project is not so important (just a personal tool), it's a WPF app.

Comment: There is nothing strange with tasks transitioning directly from `WaitingForActivation` to `RanToCompletion`. There are [two types of tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html), tasks that are associated with an `Action`, and tasks that represent an asynchronous completion. The first type is usually called "delegate task", and the second type is called "promise-style task". The `Completion` property of the dataflow blocks is an example of a promise-style task. Only the delegate tasks transition to the `Running` state during their life-cycle.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you mentioned about using `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`, could you tell me how that can be used to update the UI (which requires everything to be marshalled back to the UI thread). I think anyway we still need to use the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` (called in the UI thread)? Even if my issue related to some hidden bug, I have a feeling that it involves some heavy UI updating, if somehow we can eliminate that, the bug may simply be gone. Thanks.

Comment: The `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` cannot be used for updating the UI, because it schedules work on `ThreadPool` threads. For interacting with the UI you correctly use the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I've found the solution, it's almost my fault and sorry that some code I posted in my question is not exactly what I have (about the output result type, not a simple `int`). That way was really hard for you guys to give any suggestion. Sorry again.

Comment: Yeap, finding a bug in a Microsoft's product is not unheard of, but chances are that an inexplicable behavior is a result of a programmer's error. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually my fault, the `processingBlock` is actually blocked but it's blocked correctly and in a good way (by design).

The `processingBlock` is blocked by 2 factors:

- The `EnsureOrdered` is `true` (as by default), so the output is always queued in the processed order.
- There is at least one output result which cannot be pushed out (to some other block).

So if one output result cannot be pushed out, it will be a blocking item because of all the output results being queued in the processed order. All the after processed output results will simply be blocked (queued up) by the first output result that cannot be pushed out.

In my case the special output result that cannot be pushed out here is a `null` result. That null result can only be produced by some error (exception handling). So I have 2 blocks `okResultBlock` and `notOkResultBlock` linked to the `processingBlock`. But both those blocks are filtered to let only non-null results go through. Sorry that my question does not reflect the exact code I have, about the output type. In the question it is just a simple `int` but actually it's a class (nullable), the actual linking code looks like this:

```
processingBlock.LinkTo(okResultBlock, e => e != null && e.Point >= 9);
processingBlock.LinkTo(notOkResultBlock, e => e != null && e.Point < 9);
```

So the `null` output result will be blocked and consequentially block all the after processed result (because of the option `EnsureOrdered` being `true` by default).

To fix this, I just simply set the `EnsureOrdered` to `false` (although this is not required to avoid the blocking, but it's good in my case) and add one more block to consume the `null` output result (this is the most important to help avoid blocking):

```
processingBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<Output>(), e => e == null);
```